# NGINX show default image if not found

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

I have this NGINX conf file,
If I load any root url, it will show my default.jpg image,
but all of my mail images are stores in subfolders, eg:

```
/missing.jpg // works
/images/mising.jpg // shows nginx 404 not /default.jpg
```

Here is my nginx conf.
Note: either I can use: /default.jpg or /index.php which outputs the same image..

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php;

        server_name _;

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
                add_header Cache-control "public";
                access_log   off;
                expires 365d;
        }

        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ default.jpg;
                try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the try_files to the image cache block.

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        add_header Cache-control "public";
        access_log   off;
        expires 365d;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```